Email attachment not sending in smoketest
Actually mail is sending to the admin but attachment in it not sending if i send it from smoketest but same code works and send attachment if i send it from our website.
We need solution of this bug. I try to sending email attachment to admin in smoketest.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
